# ActiveX support in Microsoft Edge

Tags: flash, activex, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to understand the support that exists in the Microsoft Edge browser for ActiveX. I have read on numerous sources (by googling the phrase "activex edge") that this is not supported.

However.. When I look at the Adobe page at http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ it says that Flash Player is embedded in Edge using ActiveX.

screenshot here:
[image]

What does this mean, is the information on the Adobe website correct?

Comment: What is your real question though? Are you also needing to view your own customised ActiveX content in a web page? Can you not just use Internet Explorer for that part? Otherwise that notice just means Flash Player plugin is built into MS Edge (and auto-updates itself).

Comment: @VC.One no that's my question, I'm resolving conflicting information that on the one hand sources say no ActiveX in Edge but Adobe suggests with the info on its website that ActiveX does exist in Edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom ActiveX controls are definitely not supported anymore.

Since Flash is a special snowflake and there are still tons of websites which are based on it, it got special treatment and is, officially, "embedded" in Edge in some internal way. Same goes for the PDF reader. It may be that this does, technology-wise, still use ActiveX, but this should be considered an implementation detail and custom controls other than Flash are not supported anymore.

See also https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/